# My Grid system using bootstrap is not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I  wrote simple grid system using bootstrap and compiled in chrome. but those grid system is not displaying properly.

code:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gris system</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:skyblue;">col-md-3</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">col-md-1</div
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:skyblue;">col-md-3</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">col-md-1</div
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:skyblue;">col-md-3</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my output is :-

[image: issue in browser]

working code:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gris system</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-md-1" style="background-color:lavender;">col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:skyblue;">col-md-3</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:yellow;">col-md-1</div>
<div class=" col-md-3" style="background-color:lavender;">col-md-1</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:blue;">col-md-3</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:skyblue;">col-md-1</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: working code]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some CSS in your `<style>` tags which does not point to anything specific. My guess would be that the margin and padding are affecting something they're not supposed to.

Try removing that styling, otherwise everything seems all right. If it does not work, you should double-check that the Bootstrap is in fact loaded with your page.

**EDIT:** Two of your columns are actually missing a closing `>` tag after div. Double-check your closing `</div>` tags.

Comment: :- Thnak you . after removing the style tag, it is working. and i ended div tag also. But last column color "skyblue" is not filling .

Comment: The same above code i divided page into 3 columns like " col-md-4" it is working fine, even i have <style> tag also including margin and padding.

Comment: Now my code is working fine without any change. please look into that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is just some missing tag from somewhere which messes it up. An empty space can also make a difference. Always pay attention to the opening and closing tags, they're a really common cause for issues like this, and really hard to notice some times. :)